# Requested URL not founds (Django Nginx Gunicorn)

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I get the following error when trying to access any url besides the root url:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /groups/test/ was not found on this server.
```

I think the problem might be in one of the following:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from groups import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', views.home_page, name='home'),
    url(r'^groups/(.+)/$', views.view_group, name='view_group')
]
```

nginx.conf template:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name SITENAME;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ghust1995/sites/SITENAME/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/SITENAME.socket;
    }
}
```

How should this be fixed?

edit:

gunicorn-upstart template:

```
description "Gunicorn server for SITENAME"

start on net-device-up
stop on shutdown

respawn

setuid ghust1995
chdir /home/ghust1995/sites/SITENAME/source

exec ../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/SITENAME.socket itagroups.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `location /` should redirect to the port that Gunicorn Runs on.

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<Gunicorn Port>;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
```

Comment: I'll also add my upstart file that setups gunicorn. I think the unix socket is already doing whatyou say

Comment: Root URL works fine,  I dont see how I could be redirecting to the wrong port